# IndexNow not working or how long does it take?

Tags: search-engine-indexing

don't know how to send a HTTP Post request from my site so to use IndexNow for Bing I did:

Go to https://reqbin.com/post-online

Then I entered the site: https://www.bing.com/indexnow

Then I entered:

```
{

"host": "mysite",

"key": "mykey",

"keyLocation": "mykeylocation",

"urlList": [

"mysite/testurl1",

"mysite/testurl2"

]

}
```

It returned a 200(ok).

However after 4 days doing the above both testurls still show in Bing Webmaster as crawled on 01.02.24...so no change.

So my question, is the above correct? And if correct how long does it take for Bing to crawl/update those pages....Everything I read about this IndexNow(promoted by Bing) states its "immediate". Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it...above code/way of doing it is correct.
I went for it and used above example to submit/HTTP Post all my pages(around 3000) and within 12 hours Bing had updated my pages. Thanks

Comment: Any clue why your test URLs were not showing indexed for 4 days?

Comment: No clue at all....however...before I started all this in my Bing Webmaster Console it stated "Discover how IndexNow can boost etc etc"(took a screenshot but seems I can't insert that in comments) and when I submitted the test URLs 2 days later that message disappeared. So that gave me some clue that Bing might has at least noticed I'm using the IndexNow. Thanks

Comment: And it was also a good way to inform Bing about old/deleted pages(returning a 404) as per the IndexNow FAQs. They all disappeared within the approx 12 hours. Thanks

Comment: I wish Google had this